# PushViewController to the left - Simple?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to get my ViewController to slide from Left to Right at the same speed as the standard PushViewConrtoller, I'm not using a NavBar and don't want to use Modal, is there a simple way to do this, I've seen a lot of variations on different threads, but none of them work correctly!

I'm using a Navigation Controller with the following code for my Push right...

```
- (IBAction)launch1990:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"1990Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1990"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you not want to use a `UINavigationController` because of the bar? Or are you using it? What do you mean by "NavBar?"

Comment: Yeah I'm using a UINavigationController without the Bar, I need to utilise the whole view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIStroryBoard when you push view controllers, or segues, it doesn't let you customize too much. What I ended up doing was override the perform method and used QuartzCore Animations to customize our transitions.  I subclassed UIStoryBoardSegue and overwrote the perform function.

Below to customize for Push or Pop then for Segues. (For segues remember to change the class to the custom class in IB).

To do it from a normal pop or push (this does cross fade animation, adjust it for yours):

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


 - (IBAction)launch1990:(id)sender {
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .45;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"1990Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1990"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
  }
```

To do it from segue:

```
//ZHCustomSegue.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ZHCustomSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end


//  ZHCustomSegue.m
#import "ZHCustomSegue.h"
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"

@implementation ZHCustomSegue


-(void)perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .45;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush,   kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
   //transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom



    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                            forKey:kCATransition];

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for that, just tested it and works great, hoping it would work without the fade but works well.

Answer (score 5):

Use   `CATransition` with `subtype: kCATransitionFromLeft`

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
     transition.subtype= kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

Comment: This seems to work; however I see two animation, one left to right, and another right to left, at the same time.   It is very odd.  I even added a `[self.navigationController.view.layer removeAllAnimations];` before adding the animation in the code above, but still see the same.    Any idea how to make this clean?

After this code runs, I invoke a perform segue, because I have all the logic already associated to the prepareForSegue, etc.

I just need to do the transition from the left when I tap one button, and from the right when I tap another button.

Answer (score 1):

Do the normal navigation vc push, but beforehand:

```
vc.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```